# Menu in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I was looking for a mechanism to obtain a menu on the left-hand column, just like in the asciidoc website http://asciidoc.org/index.html.

When I compile the asciidoc page source http://asciidoc.org/index.txt using any of the commands given in the Overview and Examples http://asciidoc.org/index.html#_overview_and_examples, the menu isn't generated automatically. The asciidoc Cheat Sheet doesn't explain any such mechanism either. Of course, I may be missing something.

Could anyone point me to a resource that explains the correct procedure for getting such menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

- http://asciidoc.org/README-website.html
- https://github.com/asciidoc/asciidoc/tree/master/examples/website

Seems you need more than just the index.txt files to get the whole website structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, the two files layout1.css and layout2.css didn't lead to any menu. There is a toc2.css that leaves some space on the left for a menu, but that doesn't produce a menu either.

Comment: run the `./build-website.sh` script then load `index.html`.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much. This works only with the complete website files and nested directories in place.